# What's the point of using new on virtual methods?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, overriding, virtual-functions, sealed

In the following example, why does the `math` method with the `new` keyword still function even though the class that it's in derives from one where the overriden method is sealed? Isn't the whole point of having a method as `sealed` ensuring it cannot be inherited or virtual?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Utility u = new Utility();
        Entity e = new Entity();
        Last n = new Last();

        Console.WriteLine(u.math(2,3));
        Console.WriteLine(e.math(99,9));
        Console.WriteLine(n.math(4,4)); //Why doesn't this line give a compiler error?
    }
}

public class Utility
{
    public virtual int math(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
}

public class Entity : Utility
{
    public sealed override int math(int x, int y)
    {
        return x / y;
    }
}

public class Last : Entity
{
    public new int math(int x, int y)
    {
        return x * y + 100;
    }
}
```

Output:

5

11

116